# How to add multiple charts to leaflet maps?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I managed to create some bar charts on my leaflet maps and made a reference to it so that it the chart can be shown or hidden based on the checkbox in the side menu. However, only one bar chart can be shown and hidden at a time whereas I need to create several more barcharts and make them all appear at the same time when the checkbox is checked. There is a way to do this but that would mean I have to manually hard code the barcharts which is not very efficient. If you do know of a shortcut that doesnt requires hard code and still create several more barcharts and show/hidden at the same time do let me know.

```
// HTML code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Map Testing</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
        crossorigin=""/>
        <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
        <!-- Cdn for jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Cdn for Barcharts -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-dvf/0.3.1/leaflet-dvf.markers.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-d4jm/DxK0vxzigVql4lmwFikmXIlItcko9Me2md/mwI="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Event handling of checking of checkboxes -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                // Hides the piechart at the beginning
                if($(".leaflet-piechart-icon")){
                    $(".leaflet-piechart-icon").hide();
                }
                // Hides the piechart legend at the beginning
                if($(".legend")){
                    $(".legend").hide();
                }
                // Hides the stringlines at the beginning
                if($(1 == 1)){
                    mymap.removeLayer(polyline);
                }
                // Hides the barchart at the beginning
                if($(1 == 1)){
                    mymap.removeLayer(barChartMarker);
                }
                // Shows or hides layers when checkbox is checked or unchecked
                $('input[id="pie-charts"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        $(".leaflet-piechart-icon").show(500);
                        $(".legend").show(500);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        $(".leaflet-piechart-icon").hide(500);
                        $(".legend").hide(500);
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="bar-charts"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        mymap.addLayer(barChartMarker);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        mymap.removeLayer(barChartMarker);
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="choropleth"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        //$("").show(500);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        //$("").hide(500);
                    }
                });
                $('input[id="string-lines"]').click(function(){
                    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                        mymap.addLayer(polyline);
                    }
                    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                        mymap.removeLayer(polyline);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <!-- Access style.css file in the same folder -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="hamburger-menu">
                    <div class="line line-1"></div>
                    <div class="line line-2"></div>
                    <div class="line line-3"></div>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="pie-charts"> Pie Charts
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="bar-charts"> Bar Charts
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="choropleth"> Choropleth
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="navlink">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="string-lines"> String Lines
                            </label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="map">
        <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
        <script src="leaflet-choropleth.js"></script>
        </div>
        <script src="http://sashakavun.github.io/leaflet-canvasicon/leaflet-canvasicon.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet-piechart.js"></script>
        <script src="leaflet-barchart.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


// leaflet-barchart.js
var options = {
    data: {'dataPoint1': 22,'dataPoint2': 36,'dataPoint3': 42,'dataPoint4': 20},
    chartOptions: {
        'dataPoint1': {fillColor:'#3f0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint2': {fillColor:'#6a0fd1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint3': {fillColor:'#0f6ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
        'dataPoint4': {fillColor:'#0f9ad1',minValue:0,maxValue:20,maxHeight:20,displayText:function(value) {
                return value.toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    },
};
var barChartMarker = new L.BarChartMarker(L.latLng(20.894, 78.962), options).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this?